# Rails model does not load properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated my Rails application to a newer version of Rails, and now one of my models is unusable, as if it was loaded empty, as if Rails was not aware of its structure and how to populate it.

This model is Task and is based on Single Table Inheritance:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
(...)
end

class Task < Activity
(...)
end

class Event < Activity
(...)
end

class Phase < Activity
(...)
end
```

Here is what is expected when the model is loaded properly and everything works well (same model because of STI):

```
Activity.inspect       => Activity(id: integer, type: string, project_id: integer, author_id: integer, subject: text, description: text, (...), created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
Task.inspect           => Task(id: integer, type: string, project_id: integer, author_id: integer, subject: text, description: text, (...), created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
Event.inspect           => Event(same model as above ...)
(...)
```

However, since the update, Rails is unable to use the Task model at all, neither for reading a record from the database or creating a new one. Other related models Event and Phase works as expected.

When I debug it in production mode by inspecting the Task class and `Task.first` from the Task controller # show I get:

```
Task.inspect       => Task()
Task.first.inspect => #<Task >
Task.first.nil?    => false
```

This model appears as if it was void. Others models are loaded perfectly.

The application does not fail with an error when Rails tries to load the record, but it fails later when the controller tries to access any field, because the model is empty.

Some important observations :

- It only fails in production mode, but works well in development mode, or it fails only when `config.cache_classes = true` but works well otherwise.
- It works well in the Rails console.
- task.rb model file gets loaded even in the failing context. Model files structure is flat, all models are in app/models/
- It used to work well before updating from  Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.1 to Ruby 2.3.8 and Rails 3.2.22.

Comment: What field is non-existent? Does it exist when running in development mode? "...show a weird behavior". What does that mean? Clarity and conciseness are important. Please edit your question, and expand with that information, refraining from fluff; Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags, simply add the information where you would have if you'd included it initially. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648, 
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/
and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html are helpful reading.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the question.

Comment: What does your file structure look like?

Comment: app/model is flat directory of files, named according to model, classical style.  Model file task.rb is loaded (or rather "required", with cache_classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something looks buggy with respect to Rails 3.2.22 schema loading and STI.
The best workaround I found so far is to force schema reloading for this model using :

```
Task.connection.schema_cache.clear!
Task.reset_column_information
```

But then Rails looses track of STI and will miss adding the "type" field to the newly created records. So to force this fields, in every controller required, I added :

```
@task = (...).becomes(Task)
```

This feels hacky, but I could not find any better way. Maybe this tip will help someone else. In my case it was not an option to upgrade Rails further or to refactor all the code to get rid of STI.

Comment: This is the best workaround I found. If someone steps in and provide a better way to fix the situation, I'll happily give him the best answer tick.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867450/1388302

Something else is defining Task - maybe to extend it.  Don't do that.  Use prepend.  Otherwise the autoloader finds that unintentional definition and won't load the one you intend.

Or Task is now also defined by something you're including.  It might be interesting to ask about Task.superclass.

This probably came up because Rails 6 changed the autoloader.

Comment: Thank you kwerle, however I think the issue is different here. Task is only defined once in the codebase. Task.superclass == Activity (as intended).  Rails version is 3.2.22.

Comment: Oh - very old rails question - you might say 'Rails 3' in the title.